# How to setup Civicrm for using FPO addresses

Tags: addresses

I have a client that needs to use FPO addresses for contacts and members.  Is there something that needs to be configured in CiviCRM for this capability?

Carl

Comment: Silly question perhaps, but what is FPO address?

Comment: Hi, Erik! Thanks ... FPO is an original ARMY term, also known by the Navy as Fleet Post Office associated with Ships and Navy installations.  It is a location where (physical) mail can be sent and then follow defense channels for distribution.  Specific to my case, the U.S. Navy Sailing Association needs to make use of FPO addressing.

Answer (score 4):

The list of states isn't editable by the end user, so it will require filing a bug to get APO, FPO (and whatever the third one is) added as state. In the meantime, I recommend using APO as the city, and not filling in the state or country (per USPS recommendations).

Comment: Thanks, Nicholai ... I *will* file a feature/bug request for FPO/APO especially given the current need for its use.  In the meantime, we will use your recommendation.  Thanks for your input. - Carl

Answer (score 2):

Although state can not be edited in the User Interface, you will be able to add FPO addresses to the table civicrm_county using some MySQL database management tool like Phpmyadmin? If adding FPO as state is a solution that is...

Comment: Would it not be a solution to set FPO as a location type so you can add the FPO address to the contact? Or is it more fixed than that?